# Class constructor error with declarations

Tags: php, class

I am getting errors with this, NetBeans is telling me it was expecting something on the last line of the $xml_package declaration. Any ideas what I am missing?

Thank you.

```
class foo
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        public $rateRequest = 'RateV4Request';

        public $xml_request = '<'. $rateRequest. '><Revision></Revision></'.
                              $rateRequest. '>';

        public $xml_package = '<Package><Service></Service><ZipOrigination>
                        </ZipOrigination><ZipDestination></ZipDestination>
                        <Pounds></Pounds><Ounces></Ounces><Container>
                        </Container><Size></Size></Package>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the error text in your post.  Is this wrapped in `<?php ` and `?>` tags?

Comment: I have the opening <?php tag but I don't close it. I have read it is better to leave it open? But Mark's answer below fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're declaring your properties in the constructor itself, not in the class

```
class foo 
{ 
    protected $rateRequest; 

    protected $xml_request; 

    protected $xml_package; 

    public function __construct() 
    { 
        $this->rateRequest = 'RateV4Request'; 

        $this->xml_request = '<'. $this->rateRequest. '><Revision></Revision></'. 
                              $this->rateRequest. '>'; 

        $this->xml_package = '<Package><Service></Service><ZipOrigination> 
                        </ZipOrigination><ZipDestination></ZipDestination> 
                        <Pounds></Pounds><Ounces></Ounces><Container> 
                        </Container><Size></Size></Package>'; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that fixed my problem! I am trying to learn OOP and this all new to me.

Comment: hows public adequately represented with protected? And if you want to hide, suggest private and not protected.

Comment: @hakre - I could have left them as public, it's just personal habit (I'm a strong believer in getters/setters to control access to properties, but in allowing properties to be redeclared within the inheritance hierarchy

Comment: @MarkBaker: But if you like getters / setters, why do you make it protected and not private?

Comment: @hakre - comments against an answer isn't a good medium for the relative merits of different visibilities... but the simple answer is that private properties can't be redeclared in a child class

Comment: @Mark Baker: So you like setters/getters now or you like to access the members directly (in child classes). So not really getters/setters liking, right?

Comment: @hakre - public getters/setters methods allow validation before setting properties, or formatting of returned properties... within a class, I'd normally access the property directly